# svg text в вектор

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Приветствую. Экспериментирую с *svg* и столкнулся с проблемой. Для размещения текста используется `text` c делением строк на `tspan` и не понятно. что нужно применить. что-бы при импорте в *.svg*, текст превратился векторный набор точек. Приложил пример для удобности:

```html
<svg height="200" width="200" style=" font-family:arial; background: #3aaf72;">
  <text id="subtext" class="subrow" x="102" y="42" fill="#D95974" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 36px;">
    <tspan style="font-style: italic; text-transform:uppercase;" x="103.24" text-anchor="middle" y="33.24">LOrum</tspan>
    <tspan style="font-style: italic; text-transform:uppercase;" x="103.24" text-anchor="middle" y="79.24">dolorum</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="maintext" class="mainrow" x="100" y="40" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 36px;">
    <tspan style="font-style: italic; text-transform:uppercase;" x="100" text-anchor="middle" y="30">LOrum</tspan>
    <tspan style="font-style: italic; text-transform:uppercase;" x="100" text-anchor="middle" y="76">dolorum</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Yuri - зачем же Вы сниппет убрали?

Comment: @Igor, простите, автоматом :)

Comment: А зачем превращать?

Comment: Думаю, только в редакторе. На js что-то сомнительно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Допустим для печати на плоттере, плоттер не может в текст и работает только с координатами

Comment: попробуйте таким образом https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-svg.
ну или в редакторе.

Answer (score 2):

Можно преобразовать в кривые на стороне сервера, если вы можете установить дополнительное ПО. Нужно поставить Inkscape (у него есть возможность доступа к командной строке). Команда для преобразования текста в кривые будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
inkscape -f INPUT.svg --export-plain-svg=OUTPUT.svg --export-text-to-path
```

Ее можно запустить, например, через [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)